# windows phone 8 path shape binding notification issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

i am creating the favourite functionality in my windows phone 8 app. i am using shape path as the star

```
 <Path Stroke="Yellow" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Tag="{Binding BookId,Mode=OneWay}" Fill="{Binding FavouriteButton,Mode=OneWay}" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"  Margin="-14,-2,0,0" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Data="M 0,0 l 10,0 l 5,-10 l 5,10 l 10,0 l -7,10 l 2,10 l -10,-5 l -10,5 l 2,-10 Z" Tap="Path_Tap_1" />
```

my model class where the favourite button resides which ought to get changed

```
public class newreleaeslist : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public long BookId { get; set; }


    private string _FavouriteButton = "";
    public string FavouriteButton
    {
        get
        {
            return _FavouriteButton;
        }
        set
        {
            _FavouriteButton = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FavouriteButton");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

i have two list one is the newrelease list and another is the favourites list in the panorama.
when the user taps the `add to favourite star` in the newrelease list it goes to the `favourites list` in the isolated storage setting and one item is added to the favourites list. everything fine here regarding the notifications.

```
  IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        List<long> ListFavourites;
        if (settings.Contains("ListFavourites"))
        {
            ListFavourites = settings["ListFavourites"] as List<long>;
        }
        else
        {
            ListFavourites = new List<long>();
        }

        if (!ListFavourites.Contains(Convert.ToInt64(bt.Tag)))
        {
            ListFavourites.Add(Convert.ToInt64(bt.Tag));
        }
        settings["ListFavourites"] = ListFavourites;
        settings.Save();
```

1) but when i click on the `remove from favourite star` in my `favourite list`

2) the favourite star of the newrelease list should change color which it doesn't do. what could be the problem?

```
   Button bt = (Button)sender;
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        List<long> ListFavourites=new List<long>();
        if (settings.Contains("ListFavourites")) 
        {
            ListFavourites = settings["ListFavourites"] as List<long>;
        }
        ListFavourites.Remove(Convert.ToInt64(bt.Tag));
        settings["ListFavourites"] = ListFavourites;
        settings.Save();
        var item = await  bookdetailsvm.GetBookDetails(Convert.ToInt64(bt.Tag),true); 
        var favouritelists = booklistvm.BooksList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.BookId == item.BookId);

        booklistvm.BooksList.Remove(favouritelists);
        RecordCountFavouritesList.Text = booklistvm.BooksList.Count().ToString() + " records found."; 


       foreach (var items in  dashboardvm.NewReleasesbookslist)
        {
            if (items.BookId== item.BookId)
            {

              items.FavouriteButton = "Black";  // change color here
              break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to bind a `Brush` property to a string, which isn't allowed.

Change the following:

In your model,

```
private SolidColorBrush _FavouriteButton = "";
public SolidColorBrush FavouriteButton
{
    get
    {
        return _FavouriteButton;
    }
    set
    {
        _FavouriteButton = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FavouriteButton");
    }
}
```

In your `foreach`,

```
foreach (var items in  dashboardvm.NewReleasesbookslist)
{
    if (items.BookId== item.BookId)
    {
        items.FavouriteButton = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);  // change color here
        break;
    }
}
```

Let me know how that works.

EDIT:

To use colors other than what was originally posted try the following:

```
foreach (var items in  dashboardvm.NewReleasesbookslist)
    {
        if (items.BookId== item.BookId)
        {
            items.FavouriteButton = new SolidColorBrush((Color)typeof(Color).GetProperty("Black").GetValue(null, null));  // change color here
            break;
        }
    }
```

Be aware that this won't work if you make a typo or capitalization error in the strings, but it should work for basic colors pretty well.

Comment: well the poblem is that i am having a web api which have a string.how to convert from string to solidcolorbrush

Comment: ok until if someone can answer my upper question. i will be doing it using converter

Comment: I'm updating my answer with a more general solution that will let you use more colors